# How to get mean of selected rows with another column's values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

[image]

I want to take the mean of WFR between 2009-2015 for each NAME and put it for all the years of each NAME. any idea? Thanks

**How to setup**

```
data = {'NAME': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D'],
        'YEAR': [2017, 2009, 2011, 2017, 2018, 2010, 2018, 2014, 2015, 2016],
        'WFR': [20, 50, 80, 60, 90, 10, 30, 40, 55, 45]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Hello. Please update your answer with the code you have tried to use to solve this problem. Ideally you should also provide sample data and output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `groupby_mean` after filter years then map the mean for each name:

```
tmp = df.loc[df['YEAR'].between(2009, 2015)].groupby('NAME')['WFR'].mean()
df['MEAN'] = df['NAME'].map(tmp)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  NAME  YEAR  WFR  MEAN
0    A  2017   20   NaN
1    B  2009   50  65.0
2    B  2011   80  65.0
3    B  2017   60  65.0
4    B  2018   90  65.0
5    C  2010   10  10.0
6    C  2018   30  10.0
7    D  2014   40  47.5
8    D  2015   55  47.5
9    D  2016   45  47.5

>>> tmp
NAME
B    65.0
C    10.0
D    47.5
Name: WFR, dtype: float64
```

Setup:

```
data = {'NAME': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D'],
        'YEAR': [2017, 2009, 2011, 2017, 2018, 2010, 2018, 2014, 2015, 2016],
        'WFR': [20, 50, 80, 60, 90, 10, 30, 40, 55, 45]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: How can I write if the mean is NaN put the value of that year. for example for A put 20 instead of NaN in the MEAN column.

Comment: If there are multiple values for A not in the right interval like 2004, 2005, 2007, 2016, 2018. Which value(s) do you want? Maybe the global mean for A?

Comment: the value of WFR , for example for NAME A because it is not between 2009-2015 and it is one,  just put the value of WFR (20) on the MEAN column.

Comment: @MarziehKarimi. Change to `df['NAME'].map(tmp).fillna(df['WFR'])`